# How to make product image slideshows in Shopify?

Tags: slideshow, carousel, shopify, product

I'm working on a Shopify website, and I need to create a couple of image slideshows (for mobile layout only):

(1) One for the product collection

(2) One for the thumbnails of the product on the product page itself

Anybody have any idea how to accomplish either? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to look at the image loop:   https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/image

Nb - for images assigned to product variants, you'd do something like:

```
   {% for image in product.images %}
      <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'compact' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
   {% endfor %}
```

then you'd need to make sure your JS / jQuery pugin wraps around that html. For Collection images - you'd do the same, but output the images in the collection.

```
    {% for product in collection.products %}
       <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
     {% endfor %}
```

For anything cool you're going to need JavaScript. Liquid of itself just renders html - you'll need JavaScript to make stuff like whizzy slideshows. So if you're familiar with jQuery plugins - you'd just make shopify output the required html to work with the plugin.

Have you looked at Timber? Its a great place from which to start: http://shopify.github.io/Timber/

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this app: https://apps.shopify.com/product-images-gallery-slider

You can change the presentation of product images with it by choosing among slider, gallery or carousel.